# UIApplicationShortcutItem without launching

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, 3dtouch

When a user taps on a home screen menu UIApplicationShortcutItem via 3d-touch, the default behavior is for iOS to bring your app to the foreground. Is there any way to handle a UIApplicationShortcutItem selection without bringing your app to the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at this time. You can file a feedback and request this enhancement in the future

https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/